# Returning the id associated with the smallest distance between two lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm working in a list with multiple lists in the following format:

`places = [place_id: int, distance1: float, distance2: float]`

`distance1` and `distance2` are coordinates.

```
places = [
         [1, 12.2, 1.2]
         [2, 12.2, 2.3]
         [3, 22.1, 3.2]
         ]
```

I have a formula that gets me the distance between two places and one that get me a list in the form:

`d_between(place1, place2)`
`g_place(lists, place_id)`

I want my script to compare a distance between a determine place with all the other places in the list, and return the `place_id` of the place that is closest to it. Let's say `2` and compare it with all the the elements on the list `1`, and `3`.

I was thinking that I can create a new list with all the distances `distances` and use `min()` to get the smallest distance; but I don't know how to make it return the `place_id` associated to the list

```
from typing import List, TextIO

def distance(places: List[list], place_id: int) -> int:
"""Return the id of the place in places, that is the closest to the place 
with id place_id


Distance between list2 and list1: 20 meters
Distance between list2 and list3: 60 meters

>>>distance(lists, 2)
1
"""
distances = []

for aplace in places:
    if aplce[0] != place_id:
        distances.append(aplace)

for aplace in distance:
    d_beetween(aplace, g_place(places, place_id))
```

From here I'm looping between all lists, but not sure how to get the id of the closest place

Edit: Can't use the help of modules other than `math` and `csv`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I basically did this, so long...

```
p_list = []
p_min_list = []

for alist in places:
    if alist[0] != place_id:
        p_list.append(alist)

for aplace in p_list:
    b_min.append((aplace[0], d_between(aplace, g_place(places, place_id))))

for avalue in p_min_list:
    return min(p_min)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Save a tuple `(id, distance)` instead of just the `distance` and specify the `min` key as `x[1]` to use the `distance` as reference. That way, your function will return a tuple `(id, min_distance)`

```
distances = []

for aplace in places:
    if d_between(aplace, place_id):
        distances.append((aplace[0], d_between))
return min(s_distances, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you would use the `key` argument of `min()`, which must be given as a keyword argument. The value should be a function which takes a single argument, the list element (in your case the ID), and returns the value which should be compared to determine the minimum (in your case the distance to the reference location).

```
def distance_from_id(place) -> float:
    place_id = place[0]
    # ...
    return distance

min((p in places if p[0] != reference_id), key=distance_from_id)
```

You can of course use a lambda function for the `key` if you prefer.

I specified `(p in places if p[0] != reference_id)` instead of just `places` because you should exclude the reference location (the one you're calculating distance from); otherwise it will have a distance of zero and will always be the returned place. There are a few ways to do that exclusion.